# Synchronization (Operating Systems)

Tags: operating-system, semaphore

this is a problem I faced in my operating system's exam. I could not figure out the right answer for it. Can someone help.Given is a code for synchronization where many threads are trying to access a global counter g using lock-

```
if(lock==1)
wait(); //sleep this thread until some other thread wakes up this thread
else
lock=1; //enter in protected area                 
//access global counter g//
lock=0;
//wake up some other thread which is waiting for the lock to be released
```

What is the problem in above synchronization? Choose anyone of the options given below

1. The synchronization is fine and will run correctly.
2. Will only run on uni-processor systems but not on multiprocessor systems.
3. Will not run on any system
4. Can’t say. Need more data

Comment: What does `lock=1` mean? Is the setting and testing of `lock` supposed to be atomic? Is the locking interacting with the wait queue?

Comment: I think lock=1 when someone is accessing the variable. It is 0 when somebody is not

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 3. This code fails both at safety and liveness as long as threads can be preempted. For safety, consider the following interleaving of operations with two threads *t1* and *t2*:

- *t1* checks `lock`, skips to the else statement
- OS preempts *t1* and schedules *t2*
- *t2* checks `lock`, skips to the else statement

And we have two threads in the critical section. This is why you need some sort of atomic test-and-set operation, or the ability to disable preemption, to do it properly.

For liveness, consider the following interleaving of operations with two threads *t1* and *t2*:

- *t1* checks `lock`, skips to the else statement
- *t1* sets lock to 1
- OS preempts *t1* and schedules *t2*
- *t2* checks `lock`, finds 1
- OS preemtps *t2* and schedules *t1*
- *t1* sets `lock` to 0
- *t1* finds no thread waiting and does nothing else
- OS schedules *t2* again
- *t2* starts waiting...

And thus *t2* is (potentially) waiting forever. The solution is for the synchronization primitive to keep track of wake-ups (e.g., a semaphore) or require that testing the condition and waiting is done atomically (e.g., mutexes and condition variables).